# How to write to Access DB using Powershell

Tags: database, powershell, ms-access

So I found this code that allows me to build an access db. How do I add read input to insert a values to fill the fields?

```
Function Create-DataBase($Db){

 $application = New-Object -ComObject Access.Application
 $application.NewCurrentDataBase($Db,10)
 $application.CloseCurrentDataBase()
 $application.Quit()
}
Function Invoke-ADOCommand($Db, $Command){
 $connection = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection
 $connection.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$Db")
 $connection.Execute($command)
 $connection.Close()
}
$Db = "C:\ScheduledCodeRun\CollatedData\Test.mdb"
$table = "MyTest"
$Fields = "F1 Counter, F2 Date, F3 Integer, F4 Text"
$command = "Create Table $table($fields)"
If(Test-Path $Db){
    Write-Host 'DB already exists' -fore green
}else{
    Create-DataBase $db
    Invoke-ADOCommand $Db 'Create Table MyTest(F1 Counter, F2 Date, F3 Integer, F4 Text)'
}
```

Example
F2 I want to pull from the pc that powershell code is easy

$Date = Get-Date -format "MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss"

but how do I get that to fill that field?

Comment: Your powershell code has a function `Invoke-ADOCommand`. You use that to run an update or insert command.

Comment: Another option is to use AddNew and Update methods for recordset https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/83415-insert-datas-into-access-with-powershell. Why do you need to create table?